# Route not match a URL. When using nest the dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my React router routes defined as below.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
   <Route path="/flights" element={<Flights />}>
    <Route element={<FlightSearchForm />} index />
    <Route path="flight-results" element={<FlightResults />}>
     <Route path=":flight-id" element={<h1>Yes Lord</h1>} />
    </Route>
   </Route>
   <Route path="/hotels" element={<Hotel />} />
   <Route path="/taxi" element={<Taxi />} />
  </Route>
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

However, if I go to route`/flights/flight-results/TK%201956`.

I get the error:-

> `utils.ts:794 No routes matched location /flights/flight-results/TK%201956`.

I usually generate a new route for my dynamic routes as follows

```js
<Route path="/flights/flight-results/:flight-id" element={<h1>Yes Lord</h1>} />
```

But in this context it is infeasible since I want to use the same UI as its parent component using an **Outlet** component. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Hi @AmohPrince,

If I'm understanding correctly. Then, You are trying to nest the dynamic route inside the `flight-results` route. However, the `flight-results` route does not have a **dynamic segment**, so it will not be matching this **URL**  `/flights/flight-results/TK%201956.`

So, You could try this.

```js
<Route path="/flights/flight-results/:flightId" element={<FlightResults />}>
  <Route path=":flightId" element={<h1>Yes Lord</h1>} />
</Route>
```

When you navigate to a route like `/flights/flight-results/TK%201956`. The `FlightResults` component will be rendered with the `flightId`.

Comment: I have noticed youve changed the path string for the nested route from `:flight-id` to `:flightId`? Any reason

Comment: @AmohPrince, In JavaScript, a variable name cannot contain a hyphen (-). It is not a valid JavaScript identifier.

Comment: You can use the hyphen in the URL path ```/flights/flight-results/TK%201956)```.but, the dynamic segment needs to be a valid JavaScript identifier

Comment: Dude.. What the...
A JavaScript identifier is a name given to a variable, function, or property. An identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).

Comment: and...
A string literal is a sequence of characters enclosed in quotes (single or double).

Comment: In the dynamic route parameter is ":flightId", which is a valid JavaScript identifier

Comment: The parameter name  "flightId" is used to identify the dynamic route parameter. thatwhy. and also it starts with a letter and consists of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Did you get it? What I want to say? @AmohPrince

Comment: @I have gotten it. Pardon me 